# Threading A Class Member Function; Thread Initialization Through Initializer List

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to create a tread from a class member function and initialize said thread through the class constructors initializer list.

Upon execution of thread exception is thrown during the call to `Receive_List.push_back(CurVal++)`, however this exception is avoided by simply placing a `printf()` as the first instruction in the function.

```
#include <thread>
#include <list>


class SomeClass
{
    std::thread Receive_Thread;
    std::list<unsigned int> Receive_List;

    void Receive_Main()
    {
        //printf("Hacky Way Of Avoiding The Exception\n");
        const unsigned int MaxVal = 3000;
        unsigned int CurVal = 0;
        while (CurVal < MaxVal)
        {
            Receive_List.push_back(CurVal++);
        }
    }

public:
    SomeClass() :
        Receive_Thread(std::thread(&SomeClass::Receive_Main, this))
    {}

    ~SomeClass()
    {
        Receive_Thread.join();
    }

    void ProcessReceiveList()
    {
        if (!Receive_List.empty())
        {
            printf("Received Val: %i\n", Receive_List.front());
            Receive_List.pop_front();
        }
    }

    bool IsReceiveEmpty()
    {
        return Receive_List.empty();
    }
};


int main()
{
    SomeClass* MyObject = new SomeClass();

    //
    //  Sleep for 1 second to let the thread start populating the list
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    while (!MyObject->IsReceiveEmpty())
    {
        MyObject->ProcessReceiveList();
    }

    delete MyObject;
    std::system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're observing is caused by the thread starting before the list has been initialised, giving a *data race*, which leads to undefined behaviour. Adding the `printf` delays the first access to the list, so that initialisation is more likely to be finished before it's accessed. This does *not* fix the data race though; it can be fixed by declaring the list *before* the thread:

```
std::list<unsigned int> Receive_List; 
std::thread Receive_Thread;// WARNING: must be initialised last
```

You have a further problem: all accesses to data that's modified by one thread and updated by another must be synchronised; usually by guarding it with a [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex). Without synchronisation, you again have a data race, leading to undefined behaviour.

So add a mutex to the class to guard the list:

```
#include <mutex>

class SomeClass {
    std::mutex mutex;
    //...
};
```

and lock it when you access the list

```
while (CurVal < MaxVal)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    Receive_List.push_back(CurVal++);
}
```

and likewise in the other functions that access the list.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me why uncommenting the `printf()` allows the code to execute without exception. I was under the impression that simply using the list::push and list::pop functions could be ran concurrently with no issues. Also, replacing the while loop in the main thread to `while (true) {}` still causes the exception.

Comment: @KKlouzal: Undefined behaviour often doesn't make sense. And no, standard containers aren't synchronised; you need to take care of that yourself. There is indeed another problem, which I'll add to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information. I wasn't aware that the order you declare variables in the class definition denoted the order they were initialized.